# Angular 2+ - Which cli version to install for angular 6?

Tags: angular6, angular7

I have globally installed angular v7 and cli but I need angular 6 for a project, after uninstalling angular cli which version of it do I need to install for v6, so that new project I generate with ng new is angular 6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install a specific version of the angular using the below command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@6.1.1
```

This installs the angular version 6.1.1 globally, similarly install any version you want by changing 6.1.1 in above command.

Create new project using:

```
ng new PROJECT_NAME
```

Creates a project with version 6.1.1. You can check the version in package.json file or through command line using :

```
ng version
```